# Удалить четные числа из текстового файла

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
file1 = open('test.txt', 'r')
text1 = file1.read()


import re

even_num = []
new_t=[]
for int_numbers in range(0, len(re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text1))):
    if int(re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text1)[int_numbers]) % 2 == 0:
        even_num.append(re.findall(r"[0-9]+", text1)[int_numbers])
for iii in range(0,len(re.split(r"\s|\,", text1))-1):
    if re.split(r"\s|\,", text1)[iii] not in even_num:
        new_t.append(re.split(r"\s|\,", text1)[iii])
print(new_t)
```

В результате все четные числа удалились, но у меня возникли трудности с тем чтоб записать результат в тот же файл в том же формате.Подскажите, пожалуйса

Comment: А не проще тупо регуляркой заменить все фрагменты (не-цифра - куча цифр - чётная цифра - не-цифра) на одиночный пробел или там перевод строки?

Comment: @Akina Не забывайте, что он новичок.

Comment: В чем проблема-то? Как в файл записать или как в том же формате?

Answer (score 1):

```
import re

res = re.sub('(\d+)', lambda m: m.group(1) if int(m.group(1)) % 2 else '', text)
```

или так (проверка на то, что число заканчивается на `('1','3','5','7','9')` - спасибо @VasylKolomiets за подсказку):

```
res = re.sub('(\d+)', lambda m: m.group(1) if m.group(1).endswith(tuple('13579')) else '', text)
```

результат:

```
In [438]: re.sub('(\d+)', lambda m: m.group(1) if int(m.group(1)) % 2 else '', text)
Out[438]: 'Определение целых чисел утверждает, что любое из чисел 1, , 3, , число , а также любое из чисел 671, , 35 является целым. Теперь мы легко можем привести примеры целых чисел. Например, число  – целое, число  – тоже целое, нуль – целое число (напомним, что нуль НЕ является натуральным числом, нуль – целое число), числа 999, 1, , 93, , – также являются примерами целых чисел. Все целые числа удобно представлять как последовательность целых чисел, которая имеет следующий вид: , 1, , 3, … Последовательность целых чисел можно записать и так: …, , 1547, , ,457,,345,,789. Из определения целых чисел следует, что множество натуральных чисел является подмножеством множества целых чисел. Поэтому, любое натуральное число является целым, но не любое целое число является натуральным.'
```

Comment: ну вообще-то четное заканчивается на 0*2*4*6*8 - так что можно и без деления обойтись )

Comment: @VasylKolomiets, хорошая идея, спасибо! Добавил в ответ...